# Silverlight: Use Margin in ResourceDictionary

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, resourcedictionary

i try to save an margin value in a resourcedictionary. Something like that:

xmlns:systemwindows="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows.dll" [...]
0,2,2,0

```
<systemwindows:Thickness x:Key="DefaultMarginThickness">0,2,2,0</systemwindows:Thickness>
```

Later i should be able to do something like that:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource DefaultMarginThickness}" />
</Style>
```

But when i compile the resouce dictionary i get:

Error   1   The tag 'Thickness' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows.dll'. \XAML\Style.Common.Values.xaml
Error   2   The type 'systemwindows:Thickness' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. \XAML\Style.Common.Values.xaml

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness%28v=vs.95%29.aspx you can see that System.Windows should be the right namespace. Why isnt he finding the Class Thickness?

greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a resource dictionary with Visual Studio, the default namespace is mapped such that you do not need a prefix before `Thickness`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

    <Thickness x:Key="DefaultMarginThickness">0,2,2,0</Thickness>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

i.e. the URL `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"` maps to the System.Windows namespace.